# Move the button to left is not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Im using the following code and I need to put condition to the edit and delete but 
the problem is that I want that details be close to the delete ,currenlty its
moving right ,I try with left and also with `"margin-left: 20px"` and its not moving ,
how should I do that ?move the details closer to the delete?

```
@if (ViewBag.is)
        {
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID }) |
            </td>


        }
        <td style="left: 20px">@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID })</td>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do u want something like this [demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/aashi/u7PGw/).you can position your button adding this to ur css `.right-btn{position:relative; right:10px}`

Comment: please see the image in the post

Comment: try this http://fiddle.jshell.net/aashi/u7PGw/1/ ..add a class to your <td> and make it text-align:center..or else put ur code inside a <div> having class right-btn and add css .right-btn{position:relative; right:10px}

Answer (score 1):

it is moving right because you are moving it from the `left by 20px`
you should use `margin-right:20px` to move it left

use

```
<td style="margin-right: 20px">
```

or

```
  <td style="left: -20px">
```

ie

```
 <td style="margin-right: 20px">@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID })</td>
```

or

```
 <td style="margin-left: -20px">@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID })</td>
```

**EDIT** from @aashi's comment

> It will be better if you use a `div` rather than a `td` then style
>   that div to position:relative n give right/left:0

Comment: @HolgerTans: then try left:-20px;

Comment: right,left values work with position:absolute,relative or fixed..that too i m not sure abt <td> can more or not

Comment: @aashi:i think he should use a div

Comment: ya right then style that div to position:relative n give right/left:0

Comment: @aashi:i have added your suggestion

Comment: @SajadLfc-to put all the button on div?can you provide example since Im working on table ...

Comment: thanks @SajadLfc.. and Holger can u give an image or idea how u want it in which position so that we can give solution

Comment: @SajadLfc - please see the image in the post